# How do I create an Access Token from Service Account Credentials using REST API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-authentication, service-accounts

I have created a Service Account in Google Cloud Platform and downloaded the Private Key in JSON format. I am trying to create a Compute resource  via REST API. For authentication purpose, I need an AccessToken which needs to be set as a Header of create compute resource REST API. Is there a REST API to get the Access Token from the Private Key (Without using SDK or Google Clients)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following example shows you several important steps to call Google Cloud APIs without using an SDK in Python. Similar code works in just about any language (c#, java, php, nodejs).

Change the source code with the filename of your service account Json file, your Google Zone and your Project ID.

This example will list the instances in one zone for the specified project. From this example you will know the framework to call an API to create GCE instances.

This code will show you how to:

1. How to load service account credentials from a Json file.
2. How to extract the Private Key used to sign requests.
3. How to create a JWT (Json Web Token) for Google Oauth 2.0.
4. How to set the Google Scopes (permissions).
5. How to sign a JWT to create a Signed-JWT (JWS).
6. How to exchange the Signed-JWT for a Google OAuth 2.0 Access Token.
7. How to set the expiration time. This program defaults to 3600 seconds (1 Hour).
8. How to call a Google API and set the Authorization Header.
9. How to process the returned Json results and display the name of each instance.

Example program in Python 3.x:

```py
    '''
    This program lists lists the Google Compute Engine Instances in one zone
    '''
    # Author: John Hanley
    # https://www.jhanley.com
    
    import time
    import json
    import jwt
    import requests
    import httplib2
    
    # Project ID for this request.
    project = 'development-123456'
    
    # The name of the zone for this request.
    zone = 'us-west1-a'
    
    # Service Account Credentials, Json format
    json_filename = 'service-account.json'
    
    # Permissions to request for Access Token
    scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
    
    # Set how long this token will be valid in seconds
    expires_in = 3600   # Expires in 1 hour

    def load_json_credentials(filename):
        ''' Load the Google Service Account Credentials from Json file '''
    
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
    
        return json.loads(data)

    def load_private_key(json_cred):
        ''' Return the private key from the json credentials '''
    
        return json_cred['private_key']

    def create_signed_jwt(pkey, pkey_id, email, scope):
        ''' Create a Signed JWT from a service account Json credentials file
        This Signed JWT will later be exchanged for an Access Token '''
    
        # Google Endpoint for creating OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens from Signed-JWT
        auth_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    
        issued = int(time.time())
        expires = issued + expires_in   # expires_in is in seconds
    
        # Note: this token expires and cannot be refreshed. The token must be recreated
    
        # JWT Headers
        additional_headers = {
                'kid': pkey_id,
                "alg": "RS256",
                "typ": "JWT"    # Google uses SHA256withRSA
        }
    
        # JWT Payload
        payload = {
            "iss": email,       # Issuer claim
            "sub": email,       # Issuer claim
            "aud": auth_url,    # Audience claim
            "iat": issued,      # Issued At claim
            "exp": expires,     # Expire time
            "scope": scope      # Permissions
        }
    
        # Encode the headers and payload and sign creating a Signed JWT (JWS)
        sig = jwt.encode(payload, pkey, algorithm="RS256", headers=additional_headers)
    
        return sig

    def exchangeJwtForAccessToken(signed_jwt):
        '''
        This function takes a Signed JWT and exchanges it for a Google OAuth Access Token
        '''
    
        auth_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
    
        params = {
            "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
            "assertion": signed_jwt
        }
    
        r = requests.post(auth_url, data=params)
    
        if r.ok:
            return(r.json()['access_token'], '')
    
        return None, r.text
    
    def gce_list_instances(accessToken):
        '''
        This functions lists the Google Compute Engine Instances in one zone
        '''
    
        # Endpoint that we will call
        url = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/" + project + "/zones/" + zone + "/instances"
    
        # One of the headers is "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
        headers = {
            "Host": "www.googleapis.com",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    
        h = httplib2.Http()
    
        resp, content = h.request(uri=url, method="GET", headers=headers)
    
        status = int(resp.status)
    
        if status < 200 or status >= 300:
            print('Error: HTTP Request failed')
            return
    
        j = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', ''))
    
        print('Compute instances in zone', zone)
        print('------------------------------------------------------------')
        for item in j['items']:
            print(item['name'])
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        cred = load_json_credentials(json_filename)
    
        private_key = load_private_key(cred)
    
        s_jwt = create_signed_jwt(
                private_key,
                cred['private_key_id'],
                cred['client_email'],
                scopes)
    
        token, err = exchangeJwtForAccessToken(s_jwt)
    
        if token is None:
            print('Error:', err)
            exit(1)
    
        gce_list_instances(token)
```

For more information visit my blog. I write articles like this and publish the source code to help others understand how to write software for the cloud.

[www.jhanley.com](https://www.jhanley.com)

Comment: What if we need multiple scopes for the token? The scopes variable is plural but it only accepts a string

Comment: @Parzival - Use a space character between each scope. Example "A B" for Scope A and Scope B.

Comment: You don't need to exchange the signed jwt for an access token. You can use it directly in the authorization bearer header https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth

Comment: @digenishjkl - You are correct for some Google APIs but wrong for most Google Cloud APIs. Also, Google's long-term goal is to use OAuth and OIDC for almost all APIs.

Comment: Great script, thank you. It worked for me, only thing to add is that I had to install a few dependencies that I did not have. In case it helps anyone, you can have a requirements.txt file with the following:

PyJWT==2.3.0 <br/>
requests==2.27.1<br/>
httplib2==0.20.4<br/>
cryptography==36.0.1

Then:
pip3 install -r requirements.txt

Comment: Great answer! Hard to get this from the Google documentation...

Answer (score 11):

**NOTE**: As noted in the comments, really this not a solution for the question  because it uses SDK. Anyway, as the answers seems useful for other users, I've not deleted it

There is a simpler way to generate a token from a service account, using Google libraries

```
from google.auth.transport import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account

CREDENTIAL_SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
CREDENTIALS_KEY_PATH = '/PATH/TO/SERVICE_ACCOUNT.json'

def get_service_account_token():
  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
          CREDENTIALS_KEY_PATH, scopes=CREDENTIAL_SCOPES)
  credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
  return credentials.token
```

Or if you want to use the default authentication

```
import google
from google.auth.transport import requests

CREDENTIAL_SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"] 

def get_default_token():
  credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=CREDENTIAL_SCOPES)
  credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
  return credentials.token
```

When *credentials* object is created, the token is empty, but after refreshing *credentials*, it contains the access token that can be used as header in the API requests

Comment: @Parzival - The question requires a solution without an SDK or Google clients. Based upon the question asked this answer is wrong.

Comment: @JohnHanley Ah I see. Thanks for pointing it out. Deleted my comment

Comment: Hello, do you know if we need to give specific grants/roles to the service account in order to be used to refresh the token? I have been trying to look up without success

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The same solution using JAVA

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GoogleHelper {
    public static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
        return GoogleCredentials
                .fromStream(new FileInputStream("/PATH/TO/SERVICE_ACCOUNT.json"))
                .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")
                .refreshAccessToken()
                .getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing, I was looking for this code for 2 whole days! Could you tell me how did you find this API ? I think I'm not good at googling.

Comment: @kimchoky. actually, I just transformed code from another language examples)

Comment: Nice snippet, but the question requires a solution without SDK or Google client libraries, and you are importing it in the first line